# Is a linear regression possible here?

Tags: r, data-transformation, logarithm

I would like to do a linear regression between my response "weed coverage [%]" and my predictor "soil moisture content[%]". Since the response was not normally distributed and had issues with heteroskedecity, I have decided to transform my response by applying the log. Now, I got diagnostic plots and normality-test results as seen below. My question: Can I do a simple linear regression now? Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my observations were measured on different lakes and on different dates, e.g I measured soil moisture content at Lake A, Lake B and Lake C on Date A and later on Date B and so on. That means they are dependend.. What do I need to do now?

```
-----------------------------------------------
       Test             Statistic       pvalue  
-----------------------------------------------
Shapiro-Wilk              0.9917         0.0057 
Kolmogorov-Smirnov        0.0425         0.3116 
Cramer-von Mises         31.7515         0.0000 
Anderson-Darling          0.9348         0.0177 
-----------------------------------------------
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have met two important assumptions of performing a simple linear regression analysis:

1. Approximately **Normal distribution of residuals** - seen by Residual Histogram
2. Approximately **Equal variance in residuals** - seen in Residuals vs Fitted Values plot 
   **Note:** There does seem to be a slight drift here towards more negative residuals, suggesting your model may tend to over predict higher values

The last two assumptions you should check are Linearity and Independence.

**Linearity** - simply plot your response vs predictor variables to see if there looks like a linear trend is present (as opposed to a parabola, multiple-curved line, etc)

**Independence** - Are your samples independent of each other? This is something you should know from your experiment design or should checkout from your data source.

If those assumptions are properly met, **then yes it would be appropriate to conduct a simple linear regression analysis.**

And nice job applying a transformation, just remember to interpret your units & results properly in post-analysis

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  How do I plot my response vs. predictor variable? I The problem is that I work with R and ggplot and I need to specify the method if I do a regression line in a scatterplot, e.g method = "lm" gives my a simple linear regression line. So I would have to know in advance what relationshio I have..
Also, I think my samples are dependend, because I measured the same subjects multiple times, e.g soil moisture content at lake A, lake B and lake C on Date A, and then again on Date B and so on.. That means they are dependend right? What do I do then? Mixed model?

Comment: @Effigy I think it would be best if you update your question post to include this relevant info on your study design. the "lm" method in R assumes independence and will plot a simple linear model to fit weed coverage to soil moisture. To plot this, you can use ggplot to just weed coverage as X, and soil moisture as Y

Comment: Hey, thank you, so are my observation depended? I came across that problem only for statistical tests like t-tests. There it is called "paired" or "unpaired". Is that the same with regression? I am confused.. Also, I faceted the plot by date, does that solve the independence problem? Or do I have to use mixed model?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've done the right things so far, but you should also test for autocorrelation in the residuals with Durbin-Watson.  I'm assuming your data is sequential in time.  If there is autocorrelation, you might try to account for it in a model with first differencing, Cochrane-Orcutt, or Hildreth-Lu.  In the Kutner et al. text, autocorrelation in linear models is covered in chapter 12.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!